# adding border color and rounded corner to CGMutableRefPath

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I have the following code on my drawRect:

```
  CGMutablePathRef pathRef = CGPathCreateMutable();
     CGPathMoveToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 0, 220);
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, rect.size.width, 220);
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, rect.size.width, rect.size.height);
     CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathRef, NULL, 0, rect.size.height);
     CGPathCloseSubpath(pathRef);
```

how do I add a black border to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have a context:

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

and then:

```
aColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[aColor setStroke];
CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0f);
CGContextAddPath(context, pathRef);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Comment: how do I specify the border width and stuff?

Comment: With CGContextSetLineWidth.